# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all' on Rails 4

Tags: rake, assets, precompile

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
```

I attempted all recommendations found so far.
   None of them works for me.
   I cannot run anymore the program in development and as such I cannot anymore make a new deployment online.

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '>=1.1.2'
gem 'pg', '>=0.15.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>=2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '>=4.0.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'activerecord-import', '>=0.4.1'
gem 'rubyzip2'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'psych', '~> 2.0.5'

gem 'json', '>=1.8.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '>=1.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>=4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>=3.0.0.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '>=3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate','>=0.0.9'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'jquery', '>=0.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>=2.2.1'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'gmaps4rails'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '>=0.3.20',require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '>=0.0.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>=2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '>=2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>=4.2.1'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=2.13.1'
end

My application.js is 
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '>=1.1.2'
gem 'pg', '>=0.15.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>=2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '>=4.0.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'activerecord-import', '>=0.4.1'
gem 'rubyzip2'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'psych', '~> 2.0.5'

gem 'json', '>=1.8.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '>=1.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>=4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>=3.0.0.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '>=3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate','>=0.0.9'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'jquery', '>=0.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>=2.2.1'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'gmaps4rails'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '>=0.3.20',require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '>=0.0.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>=2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '>=2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>=4.2.1'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=2.13.1'
end
```

#### application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.


*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
*= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.colReorder
*= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools
*= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
*= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools

*= require bootstrap
*= require jquery.ui.all
*= require jquery.ui.core
*= require jquery.ui.theme
*= require bootstrap-datepicker

*= require_self
*= require_tree .

*/
```

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I found the problem. When integrating bootstrap with data tables when changes are introduced in files and folder names in both sides, nothing works anymore. So I separated them, I am using bootstrap for buttons and menus and data tables html style, no bootstrap integration and work perfectly, fast and smooth. Looks like these these folks can't keep up with each other.

Answer (score 31):

I ran into a similar issue and it turned out  that at some point they started using `jquery-ui` instead of `jquery.ui` and there is no need to have the `all` part anymore

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

See the section titled [Require Specific Modules](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#require-specific-modules) on the jquery-ui-rails page for more information.

Comment: It works for rake assets:precompile and I can get the main page. But now something strange occured: all of my drop down menus are not working when click on them. Not sure what is missing now, since I removed nothing from the code.

Comment: Returns no error and I change this line in the GEMFILE to be gem 'jquery-rails', '>=3.0.0'

Comment: $ gem list jquery

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jquery (0.0.1)
jquery-datatables-rails (2.1.10.0.3, 1.12.2)
jquery-rails (3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.4, 2.3.0, 2.2.1)
jquery-ui-bootstrap-rails (0.0.2)
jquery-ui-bootstrap-rails-asset (0.0.3)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.5)

Comment: I would be interested to know at what version did this begin. Does anybody know?

Comment: I would be interested to know at what version did this begin. Does anybody know?

Edit: I looked into it. The README says the change happened with version 5: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails. The strange this is, I am using version 4.0.4, but I get an error like the one in this question unless I use `require jquery-ui`. Anyone have insight about this?