# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui' with ruby 2 and rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
```

I am getting this issue when I am trying to precompile my assets. I am running ruby 2.0 and rails 3.2.

My gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.18'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'fog'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ember-rails'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', github: 'guilleiguaran/sass-rails', branch: 'backport'
  gem 'sprockets-rails', '=2.0.0.backport1'
  gem 'sprockets', '=2.2.2.backport2'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'ember-source'
  gem 'ember-data-source'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.0'
end
```

Note: In my gemfile.lock, the jquery-ui-rails version is 5.0.

At first, I changed jquery.ui.all to jquery-ui in my application.js and application.css file.

Bit stuck now and read three related Stack Overflow questions without any luck:
[Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all' on Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855624/sprocketsfilenotfound-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui-all-on-rails-4)

Comment: did you try restart your web server?

Comment: move gem 'jquery-ui-rails' outside group :assets, add to your `application.js`: `//= require jquery-ui` and 'application.css': `*= require jquery-ui`